# Break word for transformed flexbox header

Tags: css, flexbox, react-table

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/18p67pnp47

I'm need to rotate some column headers in my react-table. This is done via:

```
writing-mode: vertical-rl;
transform: rotate(180deg);
```

However, some of the text is excessively long and I'd like to cap the height post-rotation, breaking words down to a new line. Been trying various displays, min/max height width, word-wraps, etc. and can't quite get it.

The example linked above shows the problem (Name should be on a new line) and includes all of the relevant markup. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `white-space: normal;` to your css

```
.rt-resizable-header-content {
    white-space: normal;
 }
```